# Getting a personFields mask error. I am stuck

Tags: android

How do I add personFields mask?
My code and error are below

My full code [here](https://github.com/LevisKimathi/signin/blob/e48259445f990339ec9b59a9b44f341e00db6352/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/quickstart/signin/ServerAuthCodeActivity.java)!

---

```
I/onResponse: {
"error": {
    "code": 400,
     "message": "personFields mask is required. Please specify one or more valid paths. Valid paths are documented at https:\/\/developers.google.com\/people\/api\/rest\/v1\/people\/get.", "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
}
```

Comment: I was indenting that error message :/

Comment: Do that... who stops you!

Comment: euh your edit..

Comment: You can add your edit after mine...

Comment: Make sur you don't have spaces after commas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i did some research and i found a way to pass the personFields through the post url.I can fetch name gender and emailaddress but i cannot fetch phonenumber even after authorizing access
Anybody know why?

```
    OkHttpClient client2 = new OkHttpClient();
                final Request request2 = new Request.Builder()
                        .url("https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me?personFields=names,genders,emailAddresses,phoneNumbers")
                        .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken)
                        .build();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    ListConnectionsResponse connectionsResponse = service
                    .people()
                    .connections()
                    .list("people/me")
                    .set("personFields","names,addresses,birthdays,genders,phoneNumbers,photos")
                    .execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your issue is already mentioned in the response of Google People API.

**personFields**
**string (FieldMask format)**

Required. A field mask to restrict which fields on the person are returned. Valid values are:

- addresses
- ageRanges
- biographies
- birthdays
- braggingRights
- coverPhotos
- emailAddresses
- events
- genders
- imClients
- interests
- locales
- memberships
- metadata
- names
- nicknames
- occupations
- organizations
- phoneNumbers
- photos

So, just add another parameter to you RequestBody with the key 'personFields' and a value from the previous valid values.
https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get

Comment: Hi Omar. I tryed to add this .add("personFields", "birthdays") but i still get the same error.What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I suggest you try the API Explorer in this link  (https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get) to make sure you didn't make any mistake.